# make non http calls on restful services

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs. My requirement is to make non http calls on rest web services using angularjs. Is it possible using angularjs.

If yes than what will be Request and Response objects.Like as XMLHTTPRequest and XMLHTTPResponse.

Comment: What would a non-HTTP call to a restful API look like? And given that AngularJS is a library for doing browser-based things, and browsers use HTTP to communicate with servers, ....?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "non http calls on rest web services"?

Comment: RESTful web services use HTTP by definition!

Comment: Your requirement is either badly worded or misguided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an example of non-HTTP REST protocol supported by Angular.js

In case you are looking for a non - (HTTP-REST) protocol such as SOAP, you can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example)

Providing information about the required protocol will help others to find a proper answer.

Comment: Regarding REST and HTTP, I just found a related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428163/other-rest-implementations-than-http) regarding REST and HTTP. There seems to be at least one REST implementation called [Waka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waka_%28protocol%29) that is not using HTTP.