# What does the "ful" in RESTful mean?

Tags: rest

Pedantic question. Where does the "ful" in RESTful come from?

[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) goes into what RESTful is, but not really this question.

In [What's the difference between REST & RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568834/whats-the-difference-between-rest-restful), I don't see where the suffix "ful" comes into place as a term. Again, this is a rather pedantic question.

Comment: http://www.yourdictionary.com/ful

Comment: I'm going so far to state that `RESTful`is rather used to define any (JSON) service exposed via HTTP, regardless if it tries to decouple clients from services or it violating certain constraints, while `REST` advocates try to actually achieved true decoupling which can only be achieve by following each step involved (relying on HATEOAS, using content-type negotiation, using common expressive media-types, ...). Btw, I also like [RESTfool](https://twitter.com/andreineculau/status/312136503121809408) ^^

Answer (score 8):

It's purely there to make it look and sound like the English word "[restful](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/restful):"

> Something that is restful helps you to feel calm and relaxed.

The "REST" part is "**RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer." Adding "ful" makes it possible to promote the use of the technology/pattern using a word with positive connotations.